# Generating all R-digit numbers among N digits in C++ (combinations, iterative)?

Tags: c++, iteration, combinations, generate

I have a program, where I have to generate all R-digit numbers among N digits in C++, for example for `N=3` (all digits from 1 to N inclusive) and `R=2` the program should generate `12 13 21 23 31 32`. I tried to do this with arrays as follows, but it does not seem to work correctly.

```
#define nmax 20
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n, r;
void print(int[]);

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    cin >> r;

    int a[nmax];
    int b[nmax];
    int used[nmax];

    for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
        //Filling the a[] array with numbers from 1 to n
        a[p] = n;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            b[j] = a[i];
            used[j] = 1;
            if (used[j]) {
                b[j] = a[i + 1];
            }
            used[j] = 0;
        }
        print(b);
    }

    return 0;
}

void print(int k[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        cout << k[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: _I want to ask what am I doing wrong?_  That's a pretty broad question, and will elicit a lot of opinions.  If we focus on "it does not seem to work correctly", what does it seem to do incorrectly?

Comment: What's an "R-Digit" ?

Comment: Why on earth would you do this `iteratively`?

Comment: Please don't remove your code from your question. You are degrading the quality of the question that way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can explore [***this website***](http://www.quickperm.org/01example.php) where it explains the problem and suggests the solution thoroughly.

Here is a slightly altered code:

Pay attention that time is an issue for bigger N values.

```
#define N    5   // number of elements to permute.  Let N > 2
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// NOTICE:  Original Copyright 1991-2010, Phillip Paul Fuchs

void PrintPerm(unsigned int *a, unsigned int j, unsigned int i){
   for(unsigned int x = 0; x < N; x++)
      cout << " " << a[x];
   cout << "    swapped( " << j << " , " << i << " )\n";
}

void QuickPerm(void){
   unsigned int a[N], p[N+1];
   register unsigned int i, j, PermCounter = 1; // Upper Index i; Lower Index j

   for(i = 0; i < N; i++){   // initialize arrays; a[N] can be any type
      a[i] = i + 1;   // a[i] value is not revealed and can be arbitrary
      p[i] = i;
   }
   p[N] = N; // p[N] > 0 controls iteration and the index boundary for i
   PrintPerm(a, 0, 0);   // remove comment to PrintPerm array a[]
   i = 1;   // setup first swap points to be 1 and 0 respectively (i & j)
   while(i < N){
      p[i]--;             // decrease index "weight" for i by one
      j = i % 2 * p[i];   // IF i is odd then j = p[i] otherwise j = 0
      swap(a[i], a[j]);   // swap(a[j], a[i])
      PrintPerm(a, j, i);   // remove comment to PrintPerm target array a[]
      PermCounter++;
      i = 1;              // reset index i to 1 (assumed)
      while (!p[i]) {      // while (p[i] == 0)
         p[i] = i;        // reset p[i] zero value
         i++;             // set new index value for i (increase by one)
      } // while(!p[i])
   } // while(i < N)
    cout << "\n\n ---> " << PermCounter << " permutations. \n\n\n";
} // QuickPerm()

int main(){
    QuickPerm();
} //main
```

---

Here is a list of the modified items from the original code.

1. N defined to be 5 instead of 12.
2. A Counter has been added for more informative result.
3. The original swap instructions reduced by using c++ standard libraries' `swap()` function.
4. The `getch()` has been removed.
5. The 'Display()' function has been renamed to be 'PrintPerm()'.
6. The `printf()` function has been replaced by `cout`.
7. Printing number of permutation has been added.

Comment: @JHBonarius: I can't see where the OP asked for OO. This shows the core problem. In case of need, making it OO should not be a problem.